# How to show stack trace in pudb?

Tags: python, debugging, pudb

How do I see my stack trace in `pudb`? (i.e., the equivalent of the `w` / `where` command in the `pdb` Python debugger)

References:

- [pudb on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb)
- [pudb source on github](https://github.com/inducer/pudb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such command.  The information is available in the "Stack" list in the sidebar:

[image]

Comment: I feel a bit stupid now but that screenshot helped a lot, thanks! :)